# requirejs export global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, bootbox

I am trying to use bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com) with requirejs.

main.html

```
<script>
var require = {
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        "jquery"    :['jquery-1.11.0.min'],
        "bootbox"   :['bootbox.min'],
        "bootstrap" :['//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min']
    },
    shim:
        'bootstrap' :{deps:['jquery']},
        'bootbox'   :{deps:['bootstrap'],exports: 'bootbox'}
    }
}
</script>
<script src="require.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript1.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
define(['bootbox'],function(bootbox){
    bootbox.alert("Hello world!"); // working properly
});
```

myscript1.js

```
require(['main'],function(){
    bootbox.alert("Hello world!"); // not functioning (bootbox is not defined)
});
```

Normally once bootbox plugin is loaded, we can use bootbox anywhere on the page with this: `bootbox.alert("Hello world!");` When using requirejs, I have to pass the `bootbox` variable and define it everytime when using requirejs in order to use `bootbox`. I have tried with "exports", but it doesn't seem help.

How can we have the `bootbox` variable available globally once it is loaded?

Thank you.

Comment: The whole point of require.js is not have variables available globally and to program with modules. Why don't you create a Modal 'component' which uses bootbox which you can use as and when you need it. This will encapsulate the implementation allowing you to swap out the library if you choose to use a different one for example without affecting any of the code that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Bootbox to be available globally you should include it manually with a script tag. RequireJS doesn't expose it.

However, I highly recommend against this. The whole idea of dependency frameworks such as RequireJS is that you don't define anything on global scope, but to make your dependencies explicit. This not only allows you to lazy load scripts, but it also makes it possible to later replace dependencies, e.g. for unit testing.

EDIT:
[As Louis correctly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335341/requirejs-export-global-variable#23346552) Bootbox already has AMD support. If it detects RequireJS (or any other AMD loader) it doesn't expose anything to the global scope, but since it has AMD support you also don't need to shim it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, do you know what is the purpose of "exports" in "shim"?

Comment: Exports should just be the name of the global object that the dependency usually would create: Bootbox would normally create a global `bootbox` object, thus by specifying `exports : 'bootbox'` you tell RequireJS to use that object for dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I still don't get it. Does it has any happen when I put `exports : 'bootbox'`? Can explain with maybe some example or code?

Comment: I created a short example for you [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qAqa9IDwEGLg9xVtxTAL?p=preview). Hopefully it'll make things clear for you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the deal. Bootbox detects whether it is running in an AMD loader in place (like RequireJS). If so, it won't export anything into the global space but will instead define itself as an AMD module, to be loaded by an AMD loader.

Tidoo's suggestion of loading Bootbox with a `script` tag works, if you do it carefully. You'd have to load Bootbox **before** you load RequireJS, for one thing. Otherwise, it would detect that RequireJS is loaded, determine that it is running with an AMD loader, and define itself as an AMD module. This would cause a mismatched anonymous module error from RequireJS. Another thing is that you'd have to load jQuery **outside** RequireJS and load it **before** Bootbox. So that's another `script` tag.

I'd suggest avoiding that solution by simply modifying your code to add the required dependency:

```
require(['bootbox', 'main'],function(bootbox){
    bootbox.alert("Hello world!");
});
```

Also, you must not use a `shim` configuration for Bootbox **because** it detects whether there is an AMD loader around and calls `define` by itself if it detects one. A `shim` configuration is needed only for code that does not call `define`.

Comment: This is the actual right answer! I didn't check if bootbox had amd support, I just assumed it didn't because of the shim in the question. I'll update my answer as well.

Comment: I had this same issue! After reading this answer it still took me some time to figure out. In the end the key thing is the function that is encapsulated within the `require` call in the updated `myscript1.js` by @Louis. This function - e.g. `require()`'s 2nd parameter - now itself gets a `bootbox` parameter (instead of no params).

Note that parameters to the function seem to have to be in the same order as the items in the string array that is the first array. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bartvanderwal/L1emr4up/) for an example with more params.